# - Deleted SSL Certificate still displaying on websserver - WS2016 IIS10

Tags: ssl, iis

An old SSL certificate keeps displaying to the world on my websierver even though is has even been deleted from all of th stores on the webserver computer (running WS 2016 & IIS10).  A new certificate as installed and bound to the server, but it is still showing the old one.

rebooting the server does not work. there is still some cache some place still grabbing it even thought it is gone.  I used a certutil command (found elswhere) to purge the cache (if any) and still no love.

I need someone to tell me what command to enter in powershell to stop this madness.
Please do not tell me to move to linix. I need this working now on my WS server.

Comment: Usually people need to access this machine so as to investigate and tell you what's up. That's not possible here on ServerFault. Before knowing the cause, nobody can tell you "what command to enter in powershell to stop this madness" either. Keep in mind that IIS does not only consume certificates on the local machine, but also from file shares,  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-centralized-ssl-certificate-support-ssl-scalability-and-manageability

Comment: i am guessing this is some kind of cache what WS added in 2016 that was not in a prior version that needs to be cleared.  Given that the certs have all been deleted, there is no other logical place a deleted cert would still be sitting. Surely someone has encountered this before and knows what cache of file needs to be cleared or reset.

Comment: I’ve updated certificates on different IIS instances quite regularly. Never did it not take affect immediately. Did you check the bindings are updated on the sites? Have you tried opening the site locally to see what cert is delivered? Are there any upstream proxies? There’s not whole lot here to go on, and not much troubleshooting done.